# Where to modify the shell script to put single quotes ' '

Tags: shell, ksh, ibm-mq

I have below script to alter the NL, but when it is altering it should take "NL" value into single quotes like below

```
alter nl('$NL')
```

but now below script is doint with out single quotes `alter nl($NL)`, where to modify below script to put NL value in single quotes '' ?

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [ $# != 3 ]
then
echo usage: alterNamelist.sh QMGR MQREQ NAME
fi

NL=`echo 'dis qmgr'|runmqsc $1|grep REPOSNL|sed 's/.*REPOSNL\(.*\).*/\1/' |cut -d'(' -f2|cut -d')' -f1`

echo 'define nl('$NL'_'$2') like('$NL')'|runmqsc -e $1
echo 'dis nl('$NL') names ' | runmqsc $1 | nawk '
$1~/^NAMELIST ?\(/ {nl=$0}
$1~/^NAMES ?\(/ {a=1}
a==1 {
  s0=s0 "+\n" $0
  if (/\)/) {
sub( /\)/, ","addname"\)", s0)
print "ALTER", nl, s0, "DESCR (", descr, ")"; exit
  }
}' addname="$3" descr="$2" | runmqsc -e $1
```

For information above script is doing below thing

```
alter nl($NL) names(1, 2, 3, $NAME) descr($MQREQ')
```

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
echo 'define nl('$NL'_'$2') like('$NL')'
```

to

```
echo "define nl('$NL'_'$2') like('$NL')"
```

The rest follow the same fix.

Comment: Well, what was your command line that "didn't work" and what was the output?